# PHP variable array + loop

Tags: php, arrays, api, loops

I should say first of all I'm not a PHP guy, so if anyone can help with this, I'll do my best to understand any suggestions.

I have the following code that accesses an API and outputs some of the data, via  PHP wrapper:

```
$idMovie=11;
$pelinfo = $tmdb_V3->movieDetail($idMovie);

<h1><?php echo $pelinfo[original_title]; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $pelinfo[release_date]; ?></h2>
<img src="<?php echo $pelinfo[poster_path]; ?>">
<p><?php echo $pelinfo[overview]; ?></p>
```

This works fine, it shows the data for one item. What I need to do though is show the data for many more items. So far I've just repeated the block and changed the $idMovie variable - but this is of course, is not the way to do it.

I think I need to do this:

1. Set up an array to hold each variable, so $idMovie[12,34,56,78]
2. Create a loop to go through each variable, and output the data using
   my code block above.

If anyone can point me in the right right direction, that would be most helpful.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$idMovie = array(12,34,56,78);

foreach($idMovie as $id){
   $pelinfo = $tmdb_V3->movieDetail($id);

   echo "<h1> $pelinfo[original_title] </h1>
         <h2> $pelinfo[release_date] </h2>
         <img src='$pelinfo[poster_path]'>
         <p>$pelinfo[overview]</p>";

}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's one very useful construct in PHP - [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
<?php foreach($idMovies as $idMovie): 
    $pelinfo = $tmdb_V3->movieDetail($idMovie); ?>

    <h1><?php echo $pelinfo['original_title']; ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $pelinfo['release_date']; ?></h2>
    <img src="<?php echo $pelinfo['poster_path']; ?>">
    <p><?php echo $pelinfo['overview']; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here I've used so-called 'alternative syntax', useful when PHP snippets are included in HTML template.

Yet, there's more than one way to iterate through this array. For example:

```
<?php
    $idMovies = array(11, 22, 33, 42);

    $pelHTMLs = array_map(function($id) use ($tmdv_V3) { 
       $pelInfo = $tmdv_V3->movieDetail($id);
       // perhaps you should check the result here, no?

       return <<<HTML
    <h1>$pelInfo[original_title]</h1>
    <h2>$pelInfo[release_date]</h2>
    <img src="$pelInfo[poster_path]" />
    <p>$pelInfo[overview]</p>
HTML;
    }, $idMovies);

    echo implode("\n", $pelHTMLs);
?>
```

Here I used [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) function to create an array `$pelHTMLs`, each element of which is some HTML representation of a movie data, related to an id taken from `$idMovies` array. Then all these parts are just 'joined' into a single string with 'implode' function - and echoed out.

This form is quite often used in PHP 5.3+ environments (when you can supply an anonymous function into `array_map` and similar list comprehension functions). But it actually can be done in PHP 5.2 too - you just need to extract this part into a separate function (or class method), then give its name (or array with two params - class name and method name) as 'callback' argument.

Comment: we posted same answer at practically the same time... ha! +1

Comment: Hey thanks so much, this might be a bit advanced for me, as i'm getting an error. Let me work through your code though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
while($data = $pelinfo){<h1><?php echo $pelinfo[original_title]; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $pelinfo[release_date]; ?></h2>
<img src="<?php echo $pelinfo[poster_path]; ?>">
<p><?php echo $pelinfo[overview]; ?></p>}
```

This should go through all of it.
From here you should be able to work out your girst question.

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as your pseudo-code. Here as an implementation:

```
<?php
$ids = array('12','34','56','78') //array of movie ids
$foreach($ids as $id) : //I'm a huge fan of foreach vs for
  $pelinfo = $tmdb_V3->movieDetail($id);
?>
<h1><?php echo $pelinfo[original_title]; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $pelinfo[release_date]; ?></h2>
<img src="<?php echo $pelinfo[poster_path]; ?>">
<p><?php echo $pelinfo[overview]; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$idMovieArr=array(11,22,35,...);

foreach ($idMovieArr as $key) {
$idMovie=$idMovieArr[$key];
$pelinfo = $tmdb_V3->movieDetail($idMovie);

<h1><?php echo $pelinfo[original_title]; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $pelinfo[release_date]; ?></h2>
<img src="<?php echo $pelinfo[poster_path]; ?>">
<p><?php echo $pelinfo[overview]; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

something like this